# html5 video stopped working in firefox v22

Tags: html, firefox, video

```
<video id="video"  width="1024" height="576"  autoplay="autoplay">
  <source src="epm.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
  <source src="epm.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
  <source src="epm.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
</video
```

this code used to work, and still works in other browsers (Chrome and safari) what has changed in firefox ?

Comment: Why do you put an unnecessary, superfluous and ignored closing slash on the tag?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest removing the codecs and let the browser figure out if it can play the video for itself, it's usually safest.